# How to check if php website was completely loaded with JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, callback

So I have an index.php, where inside I have some Div's like this:

```
<div id="thisDiv">
    <?php ?>
<div>
```

and in another JS file, I have a divRefresh function like this:

```
function divRefresh(id, path){
    $(id).load(path, function(){
        functionToBeCalledWhenLoaded();
    });
}
```

where ID would be the id from the div, and PATH the path to where the php file is in the server.

My problem is that the `load()` function calls the `functionToBeCalledWhenLoaded()` before even my `.php` page was completelly loaded.

Solutions tried:
callback functions.
inline `<script>` call. (this solution worked with only some people)
jquery `ready()`,`onload()`,`load()`

How do I check if my php page was completelly loaded before calling a JS function?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/ready/ And if you don't want to load jquery, then use `<body onload...>`, or just stuff your initial JS call at the **END** of the page. e.g. `<script>callme();</script></body></html>`

Comment: `$(window).load(function() { do stuff here })`  This should wait till your page is fully loaded before calling the stuff in the function

Comment: The `$(document).ready()` doesn't work in my case, since I am using `ready()` to call the `divRefresh(id, path)` in it, and putting it under the call of the function, doesn't work either. It loads the `.php` pages completelly asynchronous. I will try with `$(window).load()` and tell if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the DOM is ready while the PHP server still sends data. Here you go some suggestions that may convince the browser to understand the situation. First, try to turn it off and on again. If it doesn't help:

### Suggestion 1

Try to send `header("Content-Length: ...")` - it may convince the browser to wait until all data are sent. The ... is the byte size of the generated HTML, of course.

### Suggestion 2

Try to use output buffering:

```
<?php ob_start();?>
<div id="thisDiv">
    <?php ?>
<div>
<?php ob_end_flush();?>
```

The server will wait until the html is fully generated and then it will send it to the client, so the last data would be `...</html>`, after which the DOM will be ready and after that the JS load will launch. At least I hope so.

### Suggestion 3

At the end of the php code which you put inside `thisDiv`, insert this line

```
<img src="pixel.gif" onload="functionToBeCalledWhenLoaded()">
```

Where the pixel.gif is some real 1px invisible image, so the function will launch after the php part is done. This could work when the DOM is ready and the relevant data are sent, while the browser waits for some more data.

---

Last, but not least, it could be some cache issue. As the last resort, you could use `setTimeout(functionToBeCalledWhenLoaded,1000)` to wait another second and hope that the page will be really ready after the delay. This would be a nice example of duct-tape antipattern, an act of sheer despair.

Comment: That is exactly my problem, PHP server side taking too long to send the whole page. I thought that the Solution 3 is the best one, because if allows me not to change too much my code. The `.onload()` function is only complete after all the images were also loaded, so I could also theoretically speaking, put an `<img>` at the end of my php page, and in the `.js` file an `.onload(callback)`, it should work. Thank you very much! It is actually the second time you save me in less than 2 days!! I would kiss you if I could!

Comment: I'm glad to help. Just note that onload called on window object fires when all the images of the DOM are loaded. If called on img, it fires when that particular image is loaded. In your case the images of the partial DOM can be loaded while the PHP server still sends some data inside that div, so the onload could still fire prematurely. If the onload is on the img, it is guaranteed that the previous PHP output was sent. I still may be wrong about the assumption how the browser handles the onload, it needs to be tested.

Comment: Better go for output buffering. It improves performance also.

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery you can put the code between:

`$(document).ready(function() { }` or the shorthand version `$(function(){ }`

If you're not using jquery:

`window.onload = function(){ }`